# How to create a Unique Drop down of Employee names based on name and hire date, filtered by new hires and sorted

Tags: vba, collections, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a drop-down list of all new employees based on name and hire date on one sheet from data on another sheet.

My problem is when the code gets to this line:

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=" & Join(CollectionToArray(uniqueEmployees), ",")
```

I get a "application-Defined or object-defined" error

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim employeeWs As Worksheet
    Dim bonusWs As Worksheet
    Dim employeeRng As Range
    Dim hireDateRng As Range
    Dim newDataRng As Range
    Dim uniqueEmployees As Collection
    Dim employeeName As Variant
    Dim hireDate As Variant
    Dim NewHire As Variant
    Dim dropdownRng As Range
    
    Set employeeWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("acm new letter")
    Set bonusWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ACM Bonus")
    Set employeeRng = bonusWs.Range("C3:C" & bonusWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set hireDateRng = bonusWs.Range("E3:E" & bonusWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set newDataRng = bonusWs.Range("J3:J" & bonusWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row)
    
    Set uniqueEmployees = New Collection
    
    On Error Resume Next 'Code should go line by line to find "New" Hires
    For Each Newhire In newDataRng
        If Not employeeWs.Range("D13").Validation Is Nothing Then
            employeeWs.Range("D13").Validation.Delete
        End If
        
        If NewHire.Value <> "" Then
            employeeName = employeeRng.Cells(Application.Match(hireDate.Value, hireDateRng, 0))
            
            If Not IsError(employeeName) Then
                uniqueEmployees.Add employeeName, CStr(employeeName)
            End If
        End If
    Next hireDate
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set dropdownRng = employeeWs.Range("D13")
    With dropdownRng.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=" & Join(CollectionToArray(uniqueEmployees), ",")
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = False
        .ShowError = False
    End With
End Sub

Function CollectionToArray(col As Collection) As Variant
    Dim arr() As Variant
    ReDim arr(1 To col.Count)
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To col.Count
        arr(i) = col(i)
    Next i
    
    CollectionToArray = arr
End Function
```

I have not tried anything yet

Answer (score 0):

Changes:

- Specify `Operator` parameter
- Remove the extra `=` for `Formula1`

The code is tested with Excel 365.

```vb
    With dropdownRng.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
            AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, _
            Formula1:=Join(CollectionToArray(uniqueEmployees), ",")
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = False
        .ShowError = False
    End With
```

Microsoft reference document:

> [Validation.Add method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.validation.add?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Record a macro when you set data validation by manual. It's helpful to locate the difference. The code is tested with Excel 365.

Comment: The fix did not help, i am still getting the same error.
Not sure if this will help. in the Bonus sheet the data is as follows [Name] (Mickey Mouse); [Hire Date] (1/1/2023); [New/Rev] (New).

Comment: not sure what you mean by set data validation by manual?

Comment: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/data-validation-excel/

Comment: Does anyone else have any other ideas? if not I will close this string. thank you